# CSS style sheet class

Tags: css, xhtml

Is there a way you can have a CSS file with one class let say p.one{color:red;}

and apply it to different tags? is there a way i can get an example if this is possible?

Answer (score 5):

> with one class

That isn't a class. It is a rule-set with a selector consisting of a type selector and a class selector.

> and apply it to different tags?

Don't specify the element type. Use a class selector by itself.

```
.one { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with color name that will be easy to use.

```
.redText { color: red; }
```

Comment: Class names should describe purpose, not appearance.

Comment: I think `redText` will be more appropriate

Comment: That still describes appearance. Good class names might be `placeName`, `errorMessage` and `overdue`.